# Inverse fourier transform of kernel density estimator

Tags: statistics, proof-verification, fourier-transform, parameter-estimation

I have $$f_n(x)={(nh)}^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^n K\Bigg[\frac{x-X_k}{h}\Bigg]$$
I want to show that
$$f_n(x)={(2\pi)}^{-1}  \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-iux}k(hu)\psi_n(u) du$$

where
$$\psi_n(u)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{iux} dF_n (x)=n^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^n e^{iuX_k}$$
$$k(u)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-iuy}K(y) dy $$
$$K(y)={(2\pi)}^{-1}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{iuy}k(u) du $$

Comment: Do you mean that the second equation is the Fourier transform of the first, or that the first and second are equal to each other? Also is there any knowledge about $K$; like is it a Gaussian kernel for example?

Comment: $k(u)$ is even, and
I must prove that  first and second are equal to each other.

Comment: So in line 3 of the equations, you can't take out $e^{-iuX_k}$ from the integral because it depends on $u$. You can however, swap the summation and integral using Fubini's theorem (for all $x$ the double integral is finite because it equals the kernel density estimate at that $x$, which is bounded). Then proceed in the same way you already did.

Comment: Also, because the Fourier transform is moving in the direction of $k(u)$, you should add a negative sign to all of the exponentials. You end up swapping things out arbitrarily at line 4, but you don't need to do that if you just put the negative sign in at the beginning of the Fourier transform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f_n(x)={(nh)}^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^n {(2\pi)}^{-1}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{iu(x-X_k)}k(hu) h.du$$
$$f_n(x)={(2\pi)}^{-1} {(n)}^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^n \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{iux}e^{-iuX_k}k(hu) du$$
$$f_n(x)={(2\pi)}^{-1} {(n)}^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^n e^{-iuX_k} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{iux}k(hu) du$$
$$f_n(x)={(2\pi)}^{-1}  \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-iux}k(hu)\psi_n(u) du$$
where
$$\psi_n(u)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{iux} dF_n (x)=n^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^n e^{iuX_k}$$